# How can I test if an array contains each value from map?

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I have a map:

```
Map<String, String> abc = new HashMap<>();
```

> "key1" : "value1",
>   "key2" : "value2"

And an array:

```
String[] options= {"value1", "value2", "value3"}
```

I am creating this array as following (I am using following method to do something else which is not relevant to the question that I am asking here):

```
public String[] getOptions() {
    List<String> optionsList = getOptionsFromAMethod(WebElementA);
    String[] options = new String[optionsList.size()];
    options = optionsList.toArray(options);
    return options;
}
```

What is the best way to verify if String[] contains each value from Map?

I am thinking about doing this:

```
for (Object value : abc.values()) {
    Arrays.asList(options).contains(value);
}
```

Comment: try abc.values().containsAll(Arrays.asList(options));

Comment: Create lists from both sources, sort them, compare using `equals()`. Are you sure you want all *values*? It's usually all *keys*.

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev this may miss the case when some values show up multiple times in either place

Comment: @Arkadiy Data comes from json and it is implemented as "attrubuteName" : "atrtributeValue"

Comment: Fortunately `HashMap` maintains its **values** in a `Collection` thus that `map.values()` is actually a fast `O(1)` access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Explanation

Your current approach creates an `ArrayList` (from `java.util.Arrays`, not to confuse with the regular [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) from `java.util`) wrapping the given **array**.

You then call, for each value of the map, the `ArrayList#contains` method. However this method is **very slow**. It walks through the **whole list** in order to search for something.

Your current approach thus yields `O(n^2)` which doesn't scale very well.

---

### Solution

We can do better by using a data-structure which is designed for a fast `contains` query, namely a `HashSet`.

So instead of putting all your values into an `ArrayList` we will put them into a `HashSet` whose `contains` method is **fast**:

```
boolean doesContainAll = true;
HashSet<String> valuesFromArray = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(options));
for (String value : abc.values()) {
    if (!valuesFromArray.contains(value)) {
        doesContainAll = false;
        break;
    }
}

// doesContainAll now is correctly set to 'true' or 'false'
```

The code now works in `O(n)` which is **far better** and also **optimal** in terms of complexity.

Of course you can optimize further to speedup by constant factors. For example you can first check the size, if `options.length` is greater than `abc.values().size()` then you can directly return with `false`.

---

### JStream solution

You can also use **Java 8** and `Stream`s to simplify the above code, the result and also the procedure behind the scenes is the same:

```
HashSet<String> valuesFromArray = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(options));
boolean doesContainAll = abc.values().stream()
    .allMatch(valuesFromArray::contains);
```

---

### Insights of ArrayList#contains

Let's take a closer look into `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList`. You can find its code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.ArrayList).

Here is its code for the `contains` method:

```
public boolean contains(Object o) {
    return indexOf(o) != -1;
}
```

Lets see how `indexOf` is implemented:

```
public int indexOf(Object o) {
    E[] a = this.a;
    if (o == null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            if (a[i] == null)
                return i;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            if (o.equals(a[i]))
                return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

So indeed, in all cases the method will traverse **from left to right** through the source array in order to find the object. There is **no fancy method** that is able to **directly access** the information **whether** the **object is contained** or not, it runs in `O(n)` and not in `O(1)`.

---

### Note on duplicates

If either of your data **may contain duplicates** and you plan to **count them individually**, then you will need a slightly different approach since `contains` will not bother for the amount of duplicates.

For this you may collect your `abc.values()` first into a `List` for example. Then, every time you checked an element, you will remove the matched element from the `List`.

Alternatively you can setup a `HashMap<String, Integer>` which counts for every element its occurrences. Then, every time you checked an element, decrease the counter by one.

Comment: Instead of `HashSet::contains` it should be `valuesFromArray::contains`.

Comment: @Zabuza Thank you for all the detail explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#containsAll(java.util.Collection)

```
Arrays.asList("value1", "value2", "value3").containsAll(abc.values())
```

Comment: Doesn't `ArrayList#containsAll` search by using `ArrayList#contains` which works in `O(n)` yielding `O(n^2)` in total? That would be **far from optimal**.

Comment: [Just checked that](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.ArrayList.indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29). `ArrayList#contains` yields `O(n^2)` here. The answer looks pretty compact and neat but it is not faster than OPs approach.

Comment: @Zabuza it depends on the application. If this check is only ever performed once and abc.values() only contains 3 or 4 elements, then it will be faster to use the ArrayList version of containsAll than to allocate memory for a new HashSet, go through the ArrayList and for each element calculate its hash, put it into the HashSet, then use HashSet.contains, then release then HashSet to the garbage collector. Also, this answer's implementation is faster than the OP's because it only creates a List once, instead of calling `asList()` in a loop.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException That is correct. *awsome* or someone else might include this in the answer.

Comment: Thanks! It helped.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a stream:

```
final List<String> optionsList = Arrays.asList(options);
abc.values().stream().allMatch(optionsList::contains);
```

Comment: Looks compact but also asks the `contains` question on `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList` which is **slow**. Yields `O(n^2)` in total.